# Add refresh action on button

Tags: jasper-reports

I use the Text Field element for creation of the button. Interests a question:
Whether it is possible to make so that when pressing the button, the graph which is in the same report it was updated?

For example, on graphics data in a month are specified, when pressing the button, the graph is updated and on it data in a year are shown?

Comment: You are referring to use on jasper report server?

Comment: @Barmalei `I use the Text Field element for creation of the button` - What do you mean? Your question is unclear